# Android share intent from intentservice

Tags: android, android-intent, service, share, intentservice

I want to share multiple images from my app to other apps. On Android's developer page, I found:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, SavedImages);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

How can I use this code from an intentservice?
When using the sample code from an intentservice, my app crashes with logcat error:

> Calling startActivity from outside of an Activity context requires the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

So I added

```
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

but I still get the same error and my app crashes.

How can I use the share intent from an intentservice?

Comment: "How can I use this code from an intentservice?" -- you have no idea whether it is appropriate right now for you to be popping up an activity, as the user could be off doing something else while your `IntentService` did its work in the background.

Comment: I know that the user can do something else but I want to use the code anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

That means you create an intent object which is used to start a dialog activity for user to choose which activity to handle your shareIntent. So, in this case the intent to show chooser dialog activity need the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
You can try:

```
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to..");
chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```